# jQuery Font-Family not working inside Javascript

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I am having some issued regarding font-family.

I'm having 6 brands in my application and for each brand,I need to show using 6 different fonts.

Inside script tag,

I have to check a condition like this,

```
if(selectedbrand=="Brand1")
{
$('body').css({
"font-family":'Conv_SF Slapstick Comic'
 });
}
```

I have kept @font-face in seperate css like,

```
@font-face {
                font-family: 'Conv_SF Slapstick Comic';
                src: url('fonts/SF Slapstick Comic.eot');
                src: local('SF Slapstick Comic'), url('fonts/SF Slapstick Comic.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/SF Slapstick Comic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/SF Slapstick Comic.svg') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
}
```

But font-family is not applying as it is taking the normal jQuery CSS Fonts.

Please do recommend me a solution as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The font family you are applying to your body is:

```
"font-family":'Conv_Gotham-Medium !important'
```

However, the name you have assigned to the font you have created with `@font-face` is:

```
font-family: 'Conv_SF Slapstick Comic';
```

---

You need to use the same value in both places. Try using this:

```
font-family: 'Conv_Gotham-Medium';
```

Comment: @ Asad : I have give !important so that it will take that font without using any jQuery CSS Styles.

Comment: @AbinKoshyCheriyan You have defined the font as having the name `Conv_SF Slapstick Comic`, but you are assigning the body the font family `Conv_Gotham-Medium`. Whether or not your rule is `!important` doesn't change things.

Comment: I'm having the font-family and font-face for 6 brands. Just for reference I have used one font-face here.

Comment: Whether the font path of mine is correct??? My html pages are inside a folder " html pages " and fonts are inside " fonts " folder inside the project. Also,each fonts are having separate folders. for Eg: Fonts-->Conv_Gotham-Medium--> @ font family Conv_Gotham-Medium syntax

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the issue is with css selector

Look at this example

```
 $(selector).css(property,value)
```

Your statement

```
 $('body').css({"font-family":'Conv_Gotham-Medium !important'});
```

Change it to

```
 $('#bodyid').css(font-family, 'Conv_Gotham-Medium !important');
```

Give some id to body that way the css/jquery can identify the body tag with ease...
Hope this helps. Second the declaration of property is not like tradiotional inline css so make changes to that as well..try permutations on this..

Comment: This is unnecessary. `'body'` is a perfectly valid selector.

Comment: Hi, whether the font path I have given is wrong? My html pages are inside a folder " html pages " and fonts are inside " fonts " folder inside the project. Also,each fonts are having separate folders. for Eg: Fonts-->Conv_Gotham-Medium--> @ font family Conv_Gotham-Medium syntax.

Answer (score -2):

Go for `fontFamily` (camelcase) as the property you want to change.

Comment: Camelcasing the key name is not necessary. It is specifically mentioned in the documentation that hyphenated values work as long as they are quoted.

Comment: @ DarthVader : The syntax given by you is getting be errors. Missing ) after the argument list error is showing.